# Looking for an animation episode I can't remember the name of

Tags: story-identification, stop-motion-animation

I first saw this in a clip from the Youtube series "Childhood Trauma" where influencers would speak of what shows traumatised them as a kid. I can't find his video after hours of searching the Youtube series "Childhood Trauma" nor remember the name of Youtuber or characters of the episode, so my apologues for the vague description to follow, but here goes.

I think it was stop-animation. The main character (a girl) loses her arm and it gets replaced with a robot/monster type arm that they find but it has a life of its own and makes her really strong. She gradually replaces each limb with the robot/monster limb and turns into the robot/monster and causes havoc. The other characters put her original discarded limbs together to re-create her. Her recreated person defeats the monster/robot

A real awseome, dark philosophy hidden in there about Person and Being. At what point did she stop becoming her original person. Halfway though her limb swap? Was she a new person when reassembled and did they defeat the monster or a new self?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the youtube series you're referring to?

Comment: Valorum, I think the OP means this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9lnFky1SNs

Comment: @Pete:
One of them, at least. It looks like they have at least five on that channel.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for your feedback all!

FINALY! Found it! The original uploader deleted his video from the series that is why it was so hard to find!

Comment: Excellent! You should be able to accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

The plot you describe is very similar to the *Futurama* episode [The Six Million Dollar Mon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six_Million_Dollar_Mon). The big difference is that it is a man replacing his parts one by one, not a girl. Also, it's an animated cartoon, not stop motion.

What matches your description:

- Hermes replaces his body parts with robot parts one by one.
- Zoidberg saves all the discarded parts.
- Hermes eventually replaces his brain with a computer, becoming fully robot
- Zoidberg reassembles Hermes from all the discarded parts and his brain.
- They then battle and defeat the robot

The Futurama wiki does not list it as being similar to any other story, except that the title is based on *The Six Million Dollar **Man***.